# What is the group $C_2^4$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm trying to do a problem which asks me to show that a certain group is isomorphic to $C_2^4$. What is this group?

Comment: Without any more context, I'd guess $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2 \times C_2$.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I suspected, thanks for confirming :)

Comment: As said by @MooS, you can think about $C_2$ as $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, as additive group. If you prefer multiplication - as everybody should (just joking..) - you may think about $C_2$ as the multiplicative group $\{-1,1\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the direct product of four copies of $C_2$ (the cyclic group with $2$ elements).

So you can think of this group as $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. The elements are $(a,b,c,d)$ with $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1\}$